# Ruby on rails - reading values from a text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So let's say I have the following text fields in my `html.erb` code:

```
<p> Field 1:
  <%= text_field_tag 'field1' %>
<p> Field 2:
  <%= text_field_tag 'field 2' %>
```

And I would like to do the following:

```
<%= link_to "NextPage",
            :controller => "MyController",
            :action => "my_method",
            :textfield1 => <%-# Read what has been entered in field1 -%>,
            :textfield2 => <%-# Read what has been entered in field2 -%> %>
```

How would I do that? I haven't found a way to read what the user enters in filed 1 (or field 2) in order to add it as a parameter for `textfield1` and `textfield2` in the link.

Comment: you will have to do that with JS

Comment: @Fallenhero I don't see how I could do that. Can you provide an example? I know how to get the value from the form with JavaScript. I don't understand how to reference it as a value for `textfield1` in my `link_to`.

Comment: I think you can't do this easily. You would have to find the link in JS and replace/add to the href

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do something like (if you're using simple form gem. If not, use form_for):

```
simple_form_for :your_object, url: "/your_action_url" do |f|
  f.input :field_1, as: :string
  f.input :field_2, as: :string
  f.submit "Send data"
```

Like this, you achieve the same result as you wanted up there and it's way more simple. Good luck!

Comment: I eventually reviewed the entire way of retrieving information from the form because I figured it was probably not the right way to do it. Your solution is probably right, but I have not tested it. If someone else wants to try it, and confirm it works, I will be happy to accept it as an answer. Thank you for your help.